# Comment savoir si une tournure est figée ou a un sens inattendu ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Je me soucie des tournures figées et acceptions imprévues de la grammaire, qui entraînent cette question plus générale: Comment s'apercevoir qu'une expression idiomatique, une locution, une tournure, etc. est bien cela ? Je m’intéresse aux structures de grammaire en premier lieu. Toutefois, cette question englobe idiomes, argot, proverbes, etc.

En m'acharnant à identifier les expressions ci-dessous, j'ai perdu trop de temps. Les rechercher mot à mot était stérile et inopérant tant que je n'avais pas compris qu'il s'agissait d'expressions figées, tout ce que je désire éviter !

- **on ne peut plus** (adj) : J'ai perdu plus d'une heure avant de m'aviser que ceci n'est pas : *on + ne + pouvoir (conjugué) + plus.*
- **soit** (conjonction) : Je n'imaginais pas l'existence de cette conjonction, ne reconnaissant ce mot que comme le subjonctif du verbe *être*.
- **qui plus est** : Je pensais que cela était une erreur qui devrait être *qui est plus*.
- **(Point) à la ligne:**
- **or (conjonction)**
- **de tout repos**
- **à l’avenant**
- **en venir à :** Je me hasardais à déterminer l’antécédent de « en ». Mon intuition : *en* = *de quelque part*, qui faisait que *en venir à* signifiait pour moi « *de quelque part + venir + à (d’autre part)* »
- **à mesure (que)**
- **avoir beau** (expression) : Je pensais que cela pouvait signifier « a la beauté » ou « est beau » et n'aurais jamais soupçonné que « l'idée dominante est celle de chose espérée (exprimée par avoir beau) et de déception (exprimée par la proposition subséquente) ».
- **mettre quelqu'un au parfum** (idiome)
- **en pincer pour quelqu'un** (idiome)
- **en sus de quelque chose :** Puisque *sus* signifie *à l'attaque*, je croyais que cela se reliait à la guerre.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre cette phrase : « ce qui était stérile et inopérant avant de m'aviser de la fixation ». Surtout la fin « m'aviser de la fixation ».

Comment: Il suffit de taper dans google **expression exacte** ce que tu soupçonnes être une tournure figée. Si elle est figée google te donnera de nombreux retours qui pointeront vers des entrées de dictionnaires définissant l'expression. Par [exemple](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=en+pincer+pour+&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=).

Comment: "Comme vous le sauriez"?

Answer (score 5):

Comme beaucoup d'expressions toutes faites, elles n'ont pas vraiment d'étymologies évidentes, et si elles en ont, elles peuvent faire alors référence à du vocabulaire et des tournures désuettes de nos jours.

C'est alors plus une question d'habitude, de compréhension poussée de la langue, de pratique intensive, que d'une véritable logique, qui permettrait de savoir si telle ou telle combinaison de mots est en fait une expression idiomatique, et ne doit pas être prise et traduite littéralement.

Remarque cependant que pour beaucoup de ces expressions que tu cites en exemple, un simple coup d'œil à un dictionnaire aurait pu te fournir les définitions correspondant au sens que tu cherchais à comprendre.

Comment: (+1) Réponse de bon sens. Seule nuance, au sujet de la recherche dans un dictionnaire : c'est quand même assez difficile pour certains idiomes composés de noms très communs ou polysémiques (voir notamment les exemples *on ne peut plus (+adj)*, *qui plus est*, ou éventuellement *avoir beau (+infinitif)*). Les petits dictionnaires omettent ces usages, et les gros dictionnaires ont d'énormes articles pour ces entrées...

Comment: @RomainVALERI Absolument. C'est bien pour ça que j'ai indiqué *beaucoup de ces expressions*. Je ne voulais cependant pas faire la liste des expressions "faciles" à trouver, n'ayant pas un dictionnaire sous la main pour confirmer mes propos :)

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de règles.

Le premier signe, et le plus important, est que la signification directe ne convient pas aux contextes où l'expression est employée ou qu'elle a une structure grammaticale étrange.

Le deuxième est que le dictionnaire a une entrée pour traiter le cas (mais il faut avoir un dictionnaire assez complet).

Les pronoms *en*, *y* et les verbes pronominaux sont coutumiers du fait de donner à une expression un sens difficilement analysable.  Leur présence est donc un troisième signe.